# Most efficient way to insert large amount of combinations into table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The first table, `PeopleToRole`, lists primary keys for people and primary keys for their roles. One person can have multiple roles and thus multiple rows. `PK_People`,`PK_Role`.

The second table, `PeopleToSection`, lists primary keys for people and primary keys for their assigned sections. One person can have multiple sections and thus multiple rows. `PK_People`,`PK_Section`.

A person's roles vary by 'section'. The third table, `PeopleRoleSection`, lists ranks that people have in particular sections. `PK_People`,`PK_Role`,`PK_Section`.

My task is to take everyone that has a certain two roles in `PeopleToRoles` (ex: `PK_Role in (1,2)`), and insert those two rows into `PeopleRoleSection` for every section they belong to according to `PeopleToSection`.

I've been running in circles trying to figure this out without writing a giant messy clump of insert statements. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be more helpful.   That said, it seem you may want to consider a CROSS JOIN

Comment: I might be wrong but it sounds like you might have a normalization problem here. It sounds like `PeopleRoleSection` should be FK'd to either `PeopleToRole` or `PeopleToSection` not the respective base tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding (Sample data and desired results would help a lot for our understanding), but joining `PersonToRole` and `PersontoSection` on `PK_Person` and limiting for the two roles should do the trick, I believe:

```
INSERT INTO PeopleRoleSection (PK_Person, PK_Role, PK_Section)
SELECT ptr.PK_Person, ptr.PK_Role, pts.PK_Section 
FROM PeopleToRole ptr 
    INNER JOIN PeopleToSection pts 
        ON ptr.PK_Person = pts.PK_Person 
WHERE ptr.PK_Role IN (1,2);
```

Obviously, run that SELECT by itself before letting it loose as an `INSERT` query.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Not sure why it was so hard for me to conceptualize this :)

Comment: I can completely understand. While the join condition on person is necessary, this feels like a cross-join/cartesian-product sort of solution, and if you haven't solved a data requirement in this way, it may not be obvious at first.